# What format of files in internationalization files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on internationalization of applications. I wonder whether it is better to keep in YAML files unformatted text versions of the static example, all begin with a lowercase letter, and small caps are created each time the view (method capitalize). The advantage of the method is that when creating subsequent files translator does not need to pay attention to the size of the characters and the downside may be the time overhead associated with multiple calling the helper in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different languages have different capitalization rules so it might not be a good idea. For example I should capitalize 'i' when talking about myself in english.